# Linode VPS storage capacity

Tags: storage, vps, linode

I recently uploaded my site(a voters registration app) to a LINODE VPS 1 Gig, with 98304 MB total storage.I am expecting for a maximum of 50 million voters (maybe less for that) to register in this site until next year.My concern is, is this storage is enough to hold that number of data?Every voter is required to fill up minimal information in the form for their complete name, age, address and profession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size to store the requested information (name, age, address, profession) in text format for my personal information was about 100 Bytes. Using this as a very rough average, we can calculate the total size to store 50 million:

```
50,000,000 * 100 B = 5,000,000,000 B / 1024 B/KB / 1024 KB/MB / 1024 MB/GB = 4.66 GB
```

If you have 96 GB of storage, and if you are expecting to store only the above mentioned data, that will be more than enough even if the estimate of 4.66 GB is off by double or more.

One great advantage of Linode is that you can adjust the size of your VPS to scale with demand. So if it turns out that you do need more storage capacity after launching the app, you can upgrade seamlessly using Linode's management dashboard. Here are the instructions on Resizing a Linode:

https://www.linode.com/docs/migrate-to-linode/disk-images/resizing-a-linode